# Laravel Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to get the user permissions by using Eloquent

I have 3 tables,

the first is the **users** table,

the second is the **permissions** table

and the third is **user_permissions**

the structure is very simple

```
users
-id
-name

permissions
-id
-name

user_permissions
-user_id
-permission_id
-read
-write
-update
-delete
```

this is the code that display the user permissions:

```
$user = App\User::find(1)->first();
foreach($user->permissions as $permission){
    echo "Read".$permission->pivot->read."<br>";
    echo "Write".$permission->pivot->write."<br>";
    echo "Update".$permission->pivot->update."<br>";
    echo "Delete".$permission->pivot->delete."<br>";
}
```

it all works fine when I define the relationships this way ( in the user model):

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','user_permissions')->withPivot('read', 'create','update','delete');
}
```

but I want to write it in another way because I don't want to choose the fields that I need I just want to choose them all so when I write it like this I get an error:

```
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','user_permissions')->using('App\UserPermission');
}
```

and this is my error:

BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2440:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::using()

Comment: what Laravel version do you have?

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to choose the fields that I need I just want to choose them all

If you mean that you don't want to have to specify which fields exist in the pivot, but have it happen automatically - you can't.  From [the 5.2 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many):

> By default, only the model keys will be present on the pivot object. If your pivot table contains extra attributes, you must specify them when defining the relationship:

[Same is still true in 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

Comment: this is what i tried to do here:     return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','user_permissions')->using('App\UserPermission');
 but its not working

Comment: I am not familiar with the `using` method, and I can't find anything about it in the docs ... where is that documented?

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that, seems to be new in 5.4?  So what does your `UserPermission` model look like?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just:

```php
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Permission','user_permissions')->withPivot('read', 'create','update','delete');
```

You can define a constant/variable in your pivot model:

```php
class UserPermission extends Pivot
{
    const PIVOT_ATTRIBUTES = [
        'read', 
        'create',
        'update',
        'delete'
    ];

    // . . .
}
```

And then:

```php
public function permissions()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Permission::class, 'user_permissions')
        ->withPivot(UserPermission::PIVOT_ATTRIBUTES)
        ->using(UserPermission::class);
}
```

Now, you can update `PIVOT_ATTRIBUTES` constant in your `UserPermission` class.

Comment: `using(...)` is only available in laravel 5.4, laravel 5.3 would give you `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::using()`